# xpath returns empty list while using requests but works with selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
file = open("source_code.txt","w+")
url = "https://www.careers360.com/colleges/act-college-of-engineering-and-technology-kancheepuram"
page = session.get(url)
file.write(page.text)
content = html.fromstring(page.text)
intake = content.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-12']//table//tbody//tr//td[contains(text(),'Total Student Enrollment')]//strong")
print(intake)
```

While using this script I am getting an empty list as output.
The desired output is 100.
The same XPath works with selenium but not working with this script.
If you have any solution for this please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is html tag `tbody`

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
file = open("source_code.txt","w+")
url = "https://www.careers360.com/colleges/act-college-of-engineering-and-technology-kancheepuram"
page = session.get(url)
file.write(page.text)
content = html.fromstring(page.text)
intake = content.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-12']//table//tr//td[contains(text(),'Total Student Enrollment')]//strong")
for item in intake: 
    print(html.tostring(item))
```

result:
b' **100**'

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply.

Comment: I used 'print(intake[0].text)' to get the value - 100.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try directly like the following? You don't need to create a loop to parse the required result.

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.careers360.com/colleges/act-college-of-engineering-and-technology-kancheepuram"

with requests.Session() as s:
    page = s.get(url)
    content = fromstring(page.text)
    intake = content.xpath("//table[@class='baseUl']//td[contains(.,'Total Student Enrollment')]/strong")[0].text.strip()
    print(intake)
```